# Error Access Denied on mailboxSettings for users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to hit  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/mailboxSettings` endpoint with an auth token and in return receiving a `403 Error Access Denied` response.

I have granted both application level and delegated permissions for `MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite`. I can verify that these permissions are enabled on the installed application via examination of my decoded auth token with the `jwt.ms`. Here is the exert from the decoded token:

`"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Files.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send MailboxSettings.Read MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Sites.ReadWrite.All"`

I have also verified that the user I am requesting mailboxSettings for has been granted access via Admin Consent.

I am able to return mailboxSettings if I hit the endpoint for either the admin userId or the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/mailboxSettings` endpoint. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly I tested with Microsoft Graph Explorer and it works for me. So i would request you to test the above API call with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: No luck for me in Graph Explorer either.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying on the following?
- if you were using an Application level or delegated permission
- if your auth flow uses the v1 or v2 Azure AD endpoints
- and would you mind posting the request URL you hit in Graph Explorer to get a successful response

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your token was generated using Delegated scopes. The Delegated flavor of `MailboxSettings.Read` and `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` *may only access the currently authenticated user’s mailbox*.

In order to access other users, you need to use Application scopes.  You can read more about how these scopes work (and how to select them) in this blog post: [Application vs Delegated Scopes](https://massivescale.com/application-vs-delegated-scopes/).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, delegated token only works for reading the `mailboxSettings` of the currently authenticated user. I had enabled `mailboxSettings` as an Application scope, yet I was getting the same error. The culprit of the issue was that I was using the Auth code grant for the token.

After switching to Client Credentials grant, I am successfully retrieving an Auth token that contains the `mailboxSettings` Application level scope, and am able to get 200 responses on endpoints for all users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using app-level authentication. I added all the same privileges and it still didn't work. I then requested a new token and it all sprang into life.

I know its an old question but I think the answer to the OP is - after changing the API permissions in Entra you need to get a new token for it to take effect.